# Java char set encoding problem(from UTF8 to cp866)

Tags: java, character-encoding

How to convert text from utf8/cp1251(windows cyrillic) to DOS Cyrillic (cp866)

I find this example:

```
Charset fromCharset = Charset.forName("utf8");
Charset toCharset = Charset.forName("cp866");

String text1 = "Николай"; // my name in bulgarian
String text2 = "Nikolay"; // my name in english

System.out.println("TEXT1 :[" + toCharset.decode(fromCharset.encode(text1)).toString() + "]");
System.out.println("TEXT2 :[" + toCharset.decode(fromCharset.encode(text2)).toString() + "]");
```

And the input is:

```
TEXT1 :[╨Э╨╕╨║╨╛╨╗╨░╨╣] // WRONG
TEXT2 :[Nikolay]  // CORRECT
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What do you expect? You are encoding "Николай" using UTF-8, then decoding the encoded bytes using Cp866. The output seems reasonable to me, but you obviously expect some other magic to happen.

Answer (score 15):

First of: if you've got a `String` object, then it no longer has an encoding, it's a pure Unicode string(*)!

In Java, encodings are used *only* when you convert from bytes (`byte[]`) to a string (`String`) or vice versa. (You could theoretically do a direct conversion from `byte[]` to `byte[]` but I've yet to see that done in Java).

**If** you have some cp1251 encoded data, then it must be either a `byte[]` (i.e. an array of bytes) or in some kind of stream (e.g. provided to you as an `InputStream`).

**If** you want to provide some data as cp866, then you must provide it either as a `byte[]` or as some kind of stream (e.g. an `OutputStream).

Also: there's no such thing as "utf8/cp1251". UTF-8 and CP-1251 are pretty much unrelated character encodings. Your input is either UTF-8 or CP-1251 (or something else). It can't really be both (+).

And here's the obligatory link: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

(*) yes, strictly speaking it has an encoding and it is UTF-16, but for most purposes you can (and should) think of it as an "encodingless ideal Unicode String"
(+) strictly speaking it could be both if it's only using character that encode to the same bytes in both encodings, which is usually the ASCII subset

Comment: Why add the "Sigh..." in there? It doesn't add anything to the answer and at first glance it looks like it's belittling the OP.

Comment: Very nice explanation of various common misunderstandings wrt character encodings. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: @McStretch: you're right. It's just my initial response when I read questions like that. I only added the rest of the answer because answer with *only* "sigh" would be really nasty ;-)

Comment: I understand your initial reaction, especially since you're obviously a very knowledgeable software developer. My only qualm is that less experienced devs can be put off by such reactions, and I'd hate to turn ignorant devs away for the wrong reasons. Thanks for editing your post, I'll +1 now.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're trying to decode the output of one encoding as if it's a different one.

Imagine that you had a program which could only write out JPEGs, and another which could only read PNGs... would you expect to be able to read the output of the first program with the second?

In this case the two encodings happen to be compatible for ASCII characters, but fundamentally you're doing the wrong thing.

If you have text which is already in UTF-8, you should read that from binary data into a Unicode string using the UTF-8 encoding, and then write it out using your other encoding *to* binary data again. Unicode is the intermediate step basically, as Java's native text format. This would be the equivalent to loading the JPEG output into another program which could perform the conversion to PNG before you read it with the second app.

Answer (score 5):

Short solve for your problem:

```
 System.out.write("ВАСЯ\n".getBytes("cp866")); // its right
 System.out.println("ВАСЯ".getBytes("cp866")); // its wrong
```

Result from cmd.exe:

*C:\Documents and Settings\afram\Мои документы\NetBeansProjects\Encoding\dist>java -jar Encoding.jar*

*ВАСЯ*

*[B@1bab50a*

Comment: `System.out.write("ВАСЯ\n".getBytes("cp866"))` is wrong. The output is `Р?Р?РЎРЇ`

Comment: @Green that's likely because the encoding of your terminal is different from cp866.

Answer (score 3):

**Short:**

You decode an utf8 String as cp866. Since utf8 and cp866 only share ascii symbols everything else gets mangled.

**Long:**

Java represents Strings using UTF-16 internally, all String objects are encoded in UTF-16.

`Charset.encode()` creates a bytebuffer containing the String in the choosen encoding, in your code this converts the Java UTF-16 String into a utf-8 encoded byte-array.

`Charset.decode()` takes a bytebuffer encoded as Charset and converts this into a Java UTF-16 String. In your case **you decode a `utf-8` string with a `cp866` decoder, resulting in a mangled String.**

Since java Strings have a specified encoding you have to specify it when you read or write them. Both InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter provide ctors with a Charset argument.

Here an example on how you can convert files/streams.

```
//input the source is encoded in fromCharset
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(...,fromCharset));
//output the target will be encoded in toCharset
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(...,toCharset));
//reads a decoded String
String line = in.readLine();
while(line != null)
{
   out.println(line);
   line = in.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your console output isn't cp866. Console is one, converting is other.

Internally String in java is always unicode, charset is important for input/output operations. You haven't specified what you want to do with 'converted' string, but you should definetly see classes InputStreamReader / OutputStreamWriter. They provide charset setting for your I/O operations.

Comment: That might be an additional problem, but the basic problem is that he's chaining operations that make no sense together. Encoding some text as UTF-8 and decoding it using another encoding does not produce a useful result.

Comment: i want to send data to fiscal printer which work with DOS Cyrillic

Comment: So the OutputStreamWriter is what you need. Even if you need byte[] to send directly to port, you can benefit from Writer writing data to ByteArrayOutputStream.